# Multithread in Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading, service, windows-services

I have a Windows Service executes two functions (function 1 and function2), however function2 take 5 minutes to be executed (audit users in DB).

When I start the service, a timeout message is shown: 'ERROR: 1053'. Because function2 is slow to run, but if I comment function2, the service runs fine.

I think MultiThread is a solution to the situation, but I am never working with this, how implement MultiThread in this service?

My On Start function:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        // TODO: Add code here to start your service.
        Function1();
        Function2();

        aTimer.Enabled = true;
        eventLog1.WriteEntry("Starting");
    }
```

Comment: This question appears to be unrelated to services. You are simply asking how to create a thread. Which is a fairly simple task covered extensively in about a gazillion places already. Please use websearch.

Comment: Are both functions accessing the database?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Actually, if it weren't a service, he wouldn't have a problem. It's a problem because he's trying to do all the work on the main thread of a service in the OnStart(). If he were doing it in the main() of a console application, he wouldn't need threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a task. That would be easier.

If `Function2()` depends on `Function1()`, then you can do something like:

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    Function1();
    Function2();

    aTimer.Enabled = true;
}
eventLog1.WriteEntry("Starting");
```

I'm not sure if you want `aTimer.Enabled` called inside the `Task.Run` or outside. It depends what you're using it for.

If `Function1()` and `Function2()` are independent, you can execute them simultaneously with:

```
Task.Run(()=>
{
    Parallel.Invoke(()=>
    {
       Function1();
    },
    ()=>
    {
       Function2();
    }
}
```

This will execute `Function1()` and `Function2()` at the same time.

Comment: Not necessarily, the [docs of Parallel.Invoke say](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992634(v=vs.110).aspx): *No guarantees are made about the order in which the operations execute or **whether they execute in parallel**.*

Comment: In Windows, (clearly the environment of the poster) it will generally execute concurrently, assuming CPU availability. And of course, it also assumes that there's enough work that one function won't complete before the other gets started. There are certainly corner cases where they won't execute concurrently, but in the context of the question, it's not terribly relevant.

Answer (score 0):

```
Thread temp_thread = new Thread(function);
temp_thread.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following:

```
Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Funtion1));
Thread thread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Function2));
thread1.Start();
thread2.Start();
```

I hope this will get your work done.

Comment: You don't want to `join` in the OnStart method, the service will be killed for taking too long to return from the method.

Comment: As Scott says, the call to `.Join` in this case completely nullifies the usage of threads in the first place.

Comment: Yes the edited version is what He needs. Join will not be used.